# Progress bar to display progress based on number of files found/completed in for loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, scripting, for

Is there a progress bar that can show visually completed progress based on the number of detected files found and completed in a for loop like the one below?

```
mkdir -p hflip; for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -vf hflip -c:a copy hflip/"${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? Then please close the question by marking the answer

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to keep a string for the progress bar, fill it with some character for each file and replace them with another during your loop:

```
bar=""; for i in *.EXT; do bar=$bar-; done; for i in *.EXT; do PROGRAM OPTION1 OPTION2 "$i"; bar=${bar/-/=}; printf "%s\r" $bar; done
```

But since your `ffmpeg` gives output, it will interfere with the printing of the progress bar. You could redirect the output to `/dev/null` not to see it at all, but it may be good to know if something went wrong, so I suggest to redirect it into log files for `stdout` and `stderr`, this time printed as multi-line script to make it more readable:

```
mkdir -p hflip 
bar=""
for i in *.mp4; do
  bar=$bar-
done
for i in *.mp4; do
  ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -vf hflip -c:a copy hflip/"${i%.*}.mp4" > /tmp/log.out 2> /tmp/log.err
  bar=${bar/-/=}
  printf "%s\r" $bar
done
more /tmp/log.err
```

This will display the log with all errors after processing the files. You can also display the `log.out`, but because this is about `ffmpeg`, it likes to output a lot of stuff most people don't want to read. (-;

Comment: This code is making my `ffmpeg` commands give me `No such file or directory` errors, also I could not see a progress bar anywhere.

Comment: 1) Try with a dummy command like `sleep 1` if this progress bar is what you are looking for. 2) Your command is not changed; if it worked before, it still works; if it fails, it did fail before. 3) Of course, if your command produces output, it will interfere with the progress bar. `ffmpeg` is extremely chatty, so you need to redirect its output (to a logfile or `/dev/null`) to avoid it. If you want a progress bar *and* to see the program output, you need to define it, because obviously, there can't be a general solution. Name your command and expected way to deal with the output and bar.

Comment: Ohhh I see! Thank you! So how can I redirect output of a script.sh and see a progress bar instead?

Comment: I edited my answer to demonstrate the redirection. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind editing your answer once more and use this instead? `mkdir -p hflip; for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -vf hflip -c:a copy hflip/"${i%.*}.mp4"; done` I updated my question, very sorry for the change. Hope this is okay.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't fill your command in that loop by yourself, but okay. I updated the answer for you.

Comment: +1, @Philippos, It is simple and it works for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for a simple solution (you need the [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/) package):

```
for i in *.EXT; do PROGRAM OPTION1 OPTION2 "$(echo $i|tqdm)"; done
```

assuming there are no "funny" characters in your filenames.

Comment: How to make it work with this command? I have tried many ways but keep failing. `mkdir -p hflip; for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -vf hflip -c:a copy hflip/"${i%.*}.mp4"; done` I also updated my question, very sorry about the change.

Answer (score 1):

## I suggest two alternatives

### 1. `bash` shellscript using `pv` to show progress continuously

#### Install `pv`

```
sudo apt install pv  # in Debian and Ubuntu, other commands in other distros
```

#### Shellscript with a demo program

```
#!/bin/bash

# if only files (if directories, you may need another command)

cnt=0
for i in dir/*
do
 cnt=$((cnt+1))
done
files="$cnt"
> log
> err
for i in dir/*
do
 ls "$i" >> log 2>> err  # simulating the actual process
 sleep 2                 # simulating the actual process
 echo "$i"
done | pv -l -s "$files" > /dev/null  # progress view using lines with $i
```

#### Demo

During the process

```
$ ./pver
2.00  0:00:06 [0,00 /s] [===============>                        ] 40% ETA 0:00:09
```

After finish

```
$ ./pver
5.00  0:00:10 [ 499m/s] [======================================>] 100%
```

### 2. `bash` shellscript to show current progress status on demand

- `for` loop in the background, run the `program` and a counter `cnt`
- `while` loop looking for a character input (if `c`, then tell us about the progress)

There is no progress bar, but whenever you want, you can get a status update about the progress.

#### Shellscript with a demo program

```
#!/bin/bash

cnt=0
echo "0" > clog

program () {

ls "$1"
sleep 5
}

# main

files=$(ls -1 dir|wc -l)

for i in dir/*
do
    program "$i"
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
    echo "$cnt" > clog
done > log &

while [ "$cnt" != "$files" ]
do
 cnt=$(cat clog)
 read -sn1 -t1 chr
 if [ "$chr" == "c" ]
 then
  echo "$cnt of $files files processed; running ..."
 fi
done
echo "$cnt of $files files processed; finished :-)"
```

#### Demo

```
$ ./loop
0 of 5 files processed; running ...
3 of 5 files processed; running ...
5 of 5 files processed; finished :-)

$ cat log
dir/file1
dir/file2
dir/file3
dir/file4
dir/file w space
```